# Similar function to python mask method in R

Tags: r

I look for a function in R similar to `df.mask` in Python.

Below is my codes to replace outliers of each variable with `ymin/ymax` calculated by boxplot of ggplot2:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(feature)){
  ymin <- boxplot.stats(feature[,i])$stats[1]
  ymax <- boxplot.stats(feature[,i])$stats[5]
  idx.ymin <- (feature[,i] < ymin) & (!is.na(feature[,i]))
  idx.ymax <- (feature[,i] > ymax) & (!is.na(feature[,i]))
  feature[idx.ymin,i] <- ymin
  feature[idx.ymax,i] <- ymax
}
```

Is there an alternative way to write it more efficient?

Comment: You need to provide `feature`.

Comment: @jay.sf It's a data frame that I imported from a csv